# Why is the clock speed readout greater than the maximum?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, task-manager, overclocking, benchmarking

[image]
(click for full-size image)

What is this madness?

(I'm aware that the top number refers to the non-Turbo Boosted clock speed, but what of the others?)

Comment: I see you've added the [overclocking] tag. Might that have something to do with it?

Comment: @Indrek Obviously I overclocked it to get that speed, but I only set it to 4.4 GHz. How could it get up to 5.94?

Comment: Try checking with some other utility, like [Intel's Turbo Boost Monitor](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-031441.htm) or [HWiNFO](http://www.hwinfo.com). What speed do they report?

Comment: @Indrek Intel Turbo Boost Monitor only goes up to 4.4 GHz, but task manager still gives me a crazy number. I'm inclined to believe the Intel one, but what could be causing this inaccuracy?